# Ruby on rails: Yielding specific views in a specific places in the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, view, yield

If I have one `<%= yield %>` tag then all my views render in the same place in the layout. Can I have different `<%= yield %>` tags for different views? Is so how do I do this? Thanks

Comment: Does it matter which folder the view with content for is in? What about which controller the view is from?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Look into [ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html). You can do something like this in your views:

```erb
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <!-- sidebar content specific to this page -->
<% end %>
```

This will run the template inside the content_for block, but will not output as part of the regular template `yield` buffer, it will be stored in a separate buffer for later. Then later on, including in the layout, you can use `yield :content_name` to output the content:

```erb
<div class="content">
    <%= yield %>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <%= yield :sidebar %>
</div>
```

So in a sense you can have different `yield`s for different views, you just have to give the differing content a name with `content_for` in the views, and yield it with that same name in the layout.

Consider your case, where you want different views in different places. Let's say you have three panels, panel1, panel2, and panel3. You can do this in your layout:

```
<div id="panel1"><%= yield :panel1 %></div>
<div id="panel2"><%= yield :panel2 %></div>
<div id="panel3"><%= yield :panel3 %></div>
```

You don't even need to include a plain `<%= yield %>` if you don't want to. Then in your views, you can choose which panel to display the content in by surrounding the entire view with the appropriate `content_for`. For example, one of your views might be changed like this:

```erb
<% content_for :panel2 do %>
    <!-- Your View -->
<% end %>
```

To show in panel 2. Another one might be intended for panel 3, like this:

```erb
<% content_for :panel3 do %>
    <!-- Your View -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is good for page titles, where you do want to customize most Egbert page, but you end up having to specify it in every page. That makes it not good for stuff like hiding sidebars on authentication pages only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple `<%= yield %>` tags. You can specify each `yield` tag with names like these in the base view.

`<%= yield :head %>`

`<%= yield :footer %>`

Then use the `content_for` tag in your individual views.

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use yield and content for:

```
 For example:
 <%= yield :head %>
<% content_for :head do %>
  <title>A simple page</title>
<% end %>
```

- Refer :[layout and rendering guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)