# Rails content_for overwrites rather than appends

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I load my stylesheets and js files in `<head>` for performance reasons.

My site has multiple components and each template wants to its own extra header files in inside `<% yield(:head)`.

I tested `<% content_for :head do %>` .. but then I realize it actually overwrites rather than append to a particular section.

What do you guys use?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512486/ruby-on-rails-yielding-specific-views-in-a-specific-places-in-the-layout

Comment: @Froyo that is not what I am asking for. Unless I write multiple <% yield but I dun really want to do that

Answer (score 8):

`content_for` actually appends by default. From the documentation, if you were to do...

```
<% content_for :navigation do %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Home', :action => 'index' %></li>
<% end %>

<%#  Add some other content, or use a different template: %>

<% content_for :navigation do %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Login', :action => 'login' %></li>
<% end %>
```

If you used...

```
<ul><%= content_for :navigation %></ul>
```

It would output...

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just tested this locally on a rails 3.1.0 app to make sure this is still the case and it does this fine.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb#L139) to the source which confirm's LLoyd's version.