# Possible to create a "wrapping" partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a lot of views that have the exact same code in the beginning and the end of each document.

Is there any way in Rails to avoid this duplication?

Comment: how about `yield`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7512612/1047207

Comment: Thought about adding it to the layout?

Comment: Both of your suggestions might be working, but I have done a lot of research and haven't understood how to put things together.

Comment: You can put it all in the `app/views/layouts/application.html` if they're totally common, or put head/foot partials in `app/views/share`, for example.

Comment: @lurker That's true, doing two partials top/bottom would work.

Comment: I would also seriously look at the answer given by @Jordan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information is kind of hard to find, but this is covered in the ["Rendering partials with layouts" section of the partials documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+partials+with+layouts). Basically when you do `render partial: ...` you can use the `layout:` option to give the name of the "wrapper" layout. The partial will be rendered within the wrapper wherever you put `<%= yield %>`.